# Why doesn't java use long[] in BigInteger's mag field?

Tags: java, long-integer, biginteger, carryflag

I believe in 64-bit JVM long[] is much more efficient than int[], and it can significantly speed up RSA operations.

*Carry* is a problem in long[], but we can use some native methods to force long as unsigned, e.g. `long z = u64add(x, y, cr)`, here `cr` is a `boolean[]`, can replace `long z = x + y`.

Comment: Why not ask the [openJDK devs](https://mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo)?

Answer (score 5):

`BigInteger` supports `multiply()`, not just `add()`. Since `multiply()` is the more expensive operation, its speed is also what matters most for algorithms.

Multiplying two 64-bit integers gives a 128-bit result. There is no 128-bit integer type in Java, so getting the correct result isn't just "do the operation and shift some bits." You would have to split the two numbers into 4 32-bit pieces, multiply those, and then compose the result. Or add a JVM intrinsic so that a native 128-bit operation could be used. It's not that it *can't* be done, it's more of a cost-benefit thing.

Comment: `MUL` for x86-64 returns product in RDX:RAX, so we can build a native method like `void u64mul(long x, long y, long[] z)`, here `long[] z = new long[2]`.

Comment: Like I wrote in the answer, if you implement a new JVM intrinsic for this, you could use a native 128-bit operation. If you're limited to Java data types, there's no way to access the high 64 bits of the result.

Comment: There is `Math.multiplyHigh` since JDK 9, it's not perfect for this but at least it's not a total disaster to compute the upper 64 bits of the product